# Route with multiple Id's (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to pass multiple ID's to my controller.First for Categories and second for Food items as show in function show

My **Controller** is:

```
public function index()
{
   $Foods=Food::all();
   $Category=Categories::all();
   return view('index.welcome', compact('Foods','Category'));
}


public function show($Food_id,$Category_id)
{
   $food = Food::with('restaurant','categories')->findOrFail($Food_id);
   $category = Categories::with('food')->findOrFail($Category_id);
   return view('index.show', compact('food','category'));
 }
```

My **Routes** are:

```
Route::get('index','DetailsController@index');
Route::get('index/{Food_id?}', 'DetailsController@show');
```

But it returns me error "**Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\Detailscontroller::show()**".Where is the problem in this?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method which has 2 arguments, but in the route file you're only specifying one parameter.

Maybe your route should look something like this:

```
Route::get('index/{Food_id?}/{Category_id}', 'DetailsController@show');
```

Then you would be passing both variables.

Or modify your method declaration and remove the $Category_id parameter, as you are not passing it to the method, like this:

```
public function show($Food_id)
```

Comment: it always return me food items based on Food_id.i want URl like '/index/Category_id/Food_id' or '/index/Breakfast/foods'.

Comment: Then modify your method declaration and remove the $Category_id parameter, as you are not passing it to the method.

Comment: how I can get url like this  '/index/Category_id/Food_id' ?or if Category_id is 2 and Food_is 4 then look like  '/index/2/4'?

Comment: Route::get('index/{Category_id?}/{Food_id}', 'DetailsController@show'); should work for you. If you then go to '/index/2/4' it should work.

Comment: can we use multiple ids on one view?I have main page where I have to show all categories and foods based on category_id and food_id.

Comment: I don't understand your last question. Of course you can use multiple ids in one view.

Comment: Let say I have a view in which I have to show categories based on Category_id and also Foods based on Food_id.How I can do that?

Comment: That's really another question than the original one. You would need to ask a new question for that, and show some more code including your blade template for example, because right now I don't know where the problem is and it's not easy to provide any solution as a comment anyway because there's no formatting. The original error you encountered (Missing argument 2) should be solved now, so you could mark that answer as accepted and ask a new question for the next error you're encountering.